# HTML pages not linking to other pages in the same folder

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm trying to design a website for the first time in bootstrap and I've run into a problem I can't get my head around.
I have 5 pages inside the same directory including the index page.

**HTML**

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="rules.html">Rules</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="join.html">Want to Join?</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When I load About and Join from my index page, they load fine but when I try to open the Rules page, it redirects to parked-domain.org.

Similarly, when I am in the Join page and try to open the About or Rules Page, I run into the same problem.

I have all the html files in the directory and I can't understand what's the problem?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this the actual HTML you used? Sounds like you have an absolute URL in your anchor tag which is misspelled or something.

Comment: check the spelling of the file name itself - maybe it's "Rules.html" instead of "rules.html", or "rules.htm" instead of …html - just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Similarly skeptical as putvande is about if this is the actual HTML you are using in all of those files so I'd recommend you triple check that but here are some thoughts.

If this is actually what is happening, you may be running into a browser/OS bug, what browser and OS are you testing in?

You may want to try adding in ./ before the links to explicitly say you want it to be a relative URL in the same directory, like
`<a href="./rules.html">`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate the problem. I don't get any problems in opening any page from anyother page. Please try the following code in all pages. Then try.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WWW- WEB</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="rules.html">Rules</a></li>
      <li><a href="join.html">Join</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

THIS IS INDEX PAGE..!!

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want your href link to be relative to your base directory (absolute path)? If you are at `www.example.com/folder/thispage.html` and your base url is `www.example.com/` then a link with a leading forward slash `href="/anotherpage.html"` will actually point to `www.example.com/anotherpage.html`

If you do want a relative link, try to make the href link an absolute path `href="/folder/anotherpage.html"` and see if it works. Perhaps you may want to change the base URL by adding the `base` tag to your HTML header. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, your rules.html page redirects by itself??
Try directing your URL to the rules.html page by entering: yourdomian.com/rules.html
If it redirects im guessing there is a redirect link in your rules.html page. Hope this helps..

Comment: One thing i really dont understand is why park-domain.org?